# "Distributive" variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a variadic template class.
Its constructor should accept an instance of a specific class templated on each parameter, i.e.

```
class Foo<A>
{
public:
    Foo(Bar<A>);
};

class Foo<A, B>
{
public:
    Foo(Bar<A>, Bar<B>);
};

class Foo<A, B, C>
{
public:
    Foo(Bar<A>, Bar<B>, Bar<C>);
};
```

How can I program this?

Comment: it should be possible with partial specialization and a recursive definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<typename... T>
struct Foo {
    Foo(Bar<T>... bar);
};
```

In the constructor declaration, `Bar<T>` as a whole is the pattern that gets expanded such that e.g. for `Foo<int, long, double>` a constructor taking `Bar<int>, Bar<long>, Bar<double>` is declared.

Comment: Thanks, this works!  I also feel like I have a better understanding of the `...` operator now!